# CDF of the maximum of i.i.d. gamma random variable in closed form (or in power series)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, order-statistics, gamma-distribution

Suppose that $X_i$ is an i.i.d. Gamma random variable for $ \forall i \in \{ 1, \dots, N \}$ having CDF as follows:
\begin{align}
F_{X_i}(x; \alpha, \beta) = \frac{\gamma(\alpha, \beta x) }{\Gamma(\alpha)}
\end{align}
where $\Gamma(\cdot)$ is the Gamma function and $\gamma(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the lower incomplete gamma function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).

I want to get the CDF of the maximum of $X_i$, i.e., $Z = \max \{ X_1, \cdots, X_N \}$.
I know that $F_Z(z) = \left( F_{X_i}(z; \alpha, \beta) \right)^N$.

**Here is my question.**
Does anyone know the closed form (or at least form of power series) of the CDF of $Z$?
(Or does $Z$ follow any famous distribution?)

*What I tried is to use the followings:
\begin{align}
\gamma(s,x) &= \Gamma(s) - \Gamma(s,x), \\
\Gamma(s, x) &= (s-1)!\exp(-x) \sum_{k=0}^{s-1} \frac{x^k}{k!}, \\
F_{X_i}(z; \alpha, \beta) &= \frac{\gamma(\alpha, \beta z) }{\Gamma(\alpha)} = 1-\frac{\Gamma(\alpha, \beta z) }{\Gamma(\alpha)},
\end{align}
where $\Gamma(s,x)$ is the upper incomplete Gamma function.

Comment: Maximum of iid exponential RVs approaches Gumbel distribution for large sample size (https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Gumbel_distribution&oldid=808566336#Application)

Comment: @user54038 thanks. Can you let me know which distribution $Z$ follows if we use "min" instead of "max"?

Comment: That's actually much easier. Minimum of exponential distributions is also exponential, with rate parameter equal to the sum of the rate parameters. I'm not sure if it stays simple when you consider more general gamma distributions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an expression for the power series, although the power series coefficients themselves end up containing a difficult probability. The following is valid for the case of $\beta=1$ and integer $\alpha$. Application to other $\beta$ is straightforward since, if $X$ has a gamma distribution with parameters $\alpha$ and $1$, then $P[X\le m] = P[\beta X \le \beta m]$ and $\beta X$ is has a gamma distribution with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$. However, integer $\alpha$ seems like a harder restriction to remove, as you'll see.

I derive the power series using the properties of a Poisson process. Suppose we have a Poisson process with rate parameter 1. Then, the time $T$ until $\alpha$ events has a gamma distribution with parameters $\alpha$ and $1$. The statement $T\le m$, then, means that there were $\alpha$ events in the time interval $[0,m]$.

We want $T_1\le m, T_2 \le m, \dots , T_k \le m$ to be simultaneously true. So, that's $k$ intervals of size $m$, each of which must have $\alpha$ or more events. Let $N_i$ be the number of events in interval $i$. Our event of interest can then be re-expressed as $P[N_1 \ge \alpha, N_2 \ge \alpha, \dots, N_k \ge \alpha]$.

Let $S=\sum_{i=1}^k N_i$ be the total number of events. We can expand this using the law of total probability:

$$P[N_1 \ge \alpha, N_2 \ge \alpha, \dots, N_k \ge \alpha] = \sum_{s=k\alpha}^\infty P[N_1 \ge \alpha, N_2 \ge \alpha, \dots, N_k \ge \alpha|S=s]P[S=s]$$

$N_i$ are Poisson with rate $m$, so $S$ is Poisson with rate $km$. Conditional on $S=s$, all the $N_i's$ jointly follow a multinomial distribution with total $s$ and cell probabilities $1/k$. So this sum becomes

$$\sum_{s=k\alpha}^\infty M_{s,k,\alpha} e^{-km} \frac{(km)^s}{s!}$$

where $M_{s,k,\alpha}$ is the probability that, in a multinomial distribution with $k$ equiprobable cells and a total of $s$, you get $\alpha$ or more in each cell. Some cosmetic rearrangement to make it look more like a power series:
$$e^{-km} \sum_{s=k\alpha}^\infty M_{s,k,\alpha} k^s \frac{m^s}{s!}$$
And that's our expression for the CDF of the maximum of $k$ gamma distributions with shape parameter $\alpha$ and rate parameter $1$, as a function of $m$.

I never trust my math, so here's some R code I used to test it. First, I wrote and tested some code for those multinomial probabilities:

```
# Probability that k multinomial cells will be each have alpha or more items,
# with a total of t items and equal probabilities for each cell
fillprob <- function(t, alpha, k)
{
  if (t < alpha*k) return(0)
  if (k==0) return(1)
  # First cell values
  fsv <- alpha:t
  sum(dbinom(fsv, t, 1/k) * sapply(fsv, function(taken)
      fillprob(t-taken, alpha, k-1)))
}
fillprob(30, 4, 5)
# [1] 0.4607502
set.seed(326)
mean(apply(rmultinom(10^4, 30, rep.int(1/5, 5)), 2, function(x) all(x>=4)))
# [1] 0.4576
```

Then, comparing the power series to the "raw" calculation of the CDF:

```
raw <- function(alpha, k, m)
{
  pgamma(m, alpha, 1)^k
}
expansion <- function(alpha, k, m, order=30)
{
  sapply((k*alpha):order, function(t) fillprob(t, alpha, k) * dpois(t, k*m))
}
raw(2, 3, 5)
# 0.8835541
sum(expansion(2, 3, 5))
# 0.8833568
```

I could only test for pretty small alpha and k, since this algorithm for the multinomial probabilities scales really poorly, so I can't calculate that many terms in the expansion.

Comment: Thank you for the comments.
Do you think the similar method can be applied for deriving minimum of $N$ independent Gamma variables?